# How to get custom application claims without using Graph API (Azure AD B2C & Xamarin Forms)

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

How I can get custom application claims from Azure AD B2C, without using graph API.I am try to achieve the same for my Xamarin Forms application.

I am getting the built-in claims using the below code

```
 var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(result.IdToken);
 var user = AuthenticationResultHelper.GetUserFromResult(result);
 user.City = jwt.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "city")?.Value;
```

For getting this I am using the below Nuget Refernce

- Microsoft.Identity.Client
- System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

But unfortunately the JWT response doesn't contain the custom application claims. How I can get the custom claims without consuming graph API.

Comment: Have you tried using B2C custom policies to call a REST API to obtain the claims and include same in the token.  Please refer to [Walkthrough: Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as an orchestration step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom)